# Changed the permissions on /usr/bin

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, su

I executed

```
sudo chown -R USER /usr/bin
```

Now, when I try to "sudo" anything, I get

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

I tried

```
pkexec chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
```

and I got

```
pkexec: must be setuid root
```

I tried

```
su
```

and put in my password, but su won't accept it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have root account by default. Your password is not root's password, so it won't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps

1. Restart your computer.
2. When the BIOS's POST is about to vanish, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> until the GRUB menu appears.
3. Select *Advanded Options for Ubuntu*, then *Ubuntu, with Linux ... (recovery mode).
4. When the next screen appears, select *root* to enter single user mode.
5. Your now logged in as root, so you'll be able to execute

   ```
   chown -R root:root /usr/bin
   ```
6. Initiate a reboot by executing

   ```
   shutdown -r now
   ```
7. Select *resume*.

Comment: NOTE: For security reasons, chown generally undoes the set-uid and set-gid bits on files and directories.  So you'd have to go through and check all of these programs as well!  Thus best approach is a either a proper reinstall or a restore from one of your fine backups that were previously taken.

Answer (score 0):

type usermod -o -u 0 "usernname" with root. So, "username" can do anything. Works fine too.